# Join two dataframe based on a condition using Spark / Java

Tags: java, sql, dataframe, apache-spark

I have 3 dataframes on spark : dataframe1 , dataframe2 and dataframe3 .

I want to join  dataframe1 with an other dataframe based on a condition.

I use the following code :

```
Dataset <Row> df= dataframe1.filter(when(col("diffDate").lt(3888),dataframe1.join(dataframe2,
            dataframe2.col("id_device").equalTo(dataframe1.col("id_device")).
            and(dataframe2.col("id_vehicule").equalTo(dataframe1.col("id_vehicule"))).
            and(dataframe2.col("tracking_time").lt(dataframe1.col("tracking_time")))).orderBy(dataframe2.col("tracking_time").desc())).
                   otherwise(dataframe1.join(dataframe3,
                   dataframe3.col("id_device").equalTo(dataframe1.col("id_device")).
                           and(dataframe3.col("id_vehicule").equalTo(dataframe1.col("id_vehicule"))).
                           and(dataframe3.col("tracking_time").lt(dataframe1.col("tracking_time")))).orderBy(dataframe3.col("tracking_time").desc())));
```

But I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
```

**EDIT**

Input dataframes :

dataframe1

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| diffDate  |id_device    |id_vehicule  |tracking_time|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|222        |1            |5            |2020-05-30   |          
|4700       |8            |9            |2019-03-01   |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

dataframe2

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|id_device  |id_vehicule  |tracking_time|longitude    |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|1          |5            |2020-05-12   | 33.21111    |       
|8          |9            |2019-03-01   |20.2222      |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

dataframe3

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|id_device  |id_vehicule  |tracking_time|latitude     |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|1          |5            |2020-05-12   | 40.333      |       
|8          |9            |2019-02-28   |2.00000      |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

when diffDate < 3888

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| diffDate  |id_device    |id_vehicule  |tracking_time|id_device  |id_vehicule  |tracking_time|longitude|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+ +-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|222        |1            |5            |2020-05-30   | 1          |5            |2020-05-12   | 33.21111    |       
-----------+--------------+---------------+----------+----------+--------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

when diffDate > 3888

```
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| diffDate  |id_device    |id_vehicule  |tracking_time|id_device  |id_vehicule  |tracking_time|latitude|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+ +-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|4700        |9            |5            |2019-03-01   | 8          |9            |2019-02-28   | 2.00000    |       
-----------+--------------+---------------+----------+----------+--------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

I need your help

Thank you.

Comment: can you post a sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to revisit your code.

You are trying to execute a join for each row of the `dataframe1` (of course based on the condition), which is I think incorrect requirement or misunderstood requirement.

`when(condition, then).otherwise()` function executes for each row of the underlying dataframe and generally used to process the column based on condition. `then` and `else/otherwise` clause in the function only supports `literals` which are existing columns in the dataframe primitive/ complex types and literals. **you can't put dataframe or any operation outputting the dataframe there**

May be your requirement is to join the `datafrmae1` with `datafrmae2` for the rows where `col("diffDate").lt(3888)`. TO achieve this you can do the following -

```java
dataframe1.join(dataframe2,
                dataframe2.col("id_device").equalTo(dataframe1.col("id_device")).
                        and(dataframe2.col("id_vehicule").equalTo(dataframe1.col("id_vehicule"))).
                        and(dataframe2.col("tracking_time").lt(dataframe1.col("tracking_time"))).
                        and(dataframe1.col("diffDate").lt(3888))
                )
                        .orderBy(dataframe2.col("tracking_time").desc())
```

### Edit-1

```java
        dataframe1.as("a").join(dataframe2.as("b"),
                dataframe2.col("id_device").equalTo(dataframe1.col("id_device")).
                        and(dataframe2.col("id_vehicule").equalTo(dataframe1.col("id_vehicule"))).
                        and(dataframe2.col("tracking_time").lt(dataframe1.col("tracking_time"))).
                        and(dataframe1.col("diffDate").lt(3888))
        ).selectExpr("a.*", "b.longitude", "null as latitude")
                .unionByName(
                        dataframe1.as("a").join(dataframe3.as("c"),
                                dataframe3.col("id_device").equalTo(dataframe1.col("id_device")).
                                        and(dataframe3.col("id_vehicule").equalTo(dataframe1.col("id_vehicule"))).
                                        and(dataframe3.col("tracking_time").lt(dataframe1.col("tracking_time"))).
                                        and(dataframe1.col("diffDate").geq(3888))
                        ).selectExpr("a.*", "c.latitude", "null as longitude")
                               
                )
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. 
note that I wanted a single dataframe which ensures the filter to use it after. there is no posibility to do that ?